# How can I find the cause of a system hang from the system logs?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am running a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS in an Amazon EC2 instance.

The system suddenly became unresponsive. When I checked the log files I found the following errors in /var/log/syslog

> Feb 22 04:10:01 ip-10-0-1-12 CRON[16153]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/cm-sysmon)
>   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
>   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
>   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 kernel: imklog 4.2.0, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
>   Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.2.0" x-pid="656" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
>   Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
>   Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
>   Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output file '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
>   Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
>   Feb 22 04:29:47 ip-10-0-1-12 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu

We had to reboot the system to bring it live.

I am surprised to see the garbage values in the syslog.

Nothing suspicious in the /var/log/kern.log or in /var/log/messages.

How do I find out what went wrong during that time ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like /usr/sbin/cm-sysmon was the last command at 04:10:01 before the reboot.

At 04:29:47 the system was up and running again, but had problems connecting to the console.

I guess the latter is a EC2 problem caused by the sudden reboot.

Best guess is to have a look at /usr/sbin/cm-sysmon - but that could be completely innocent.

The garbage looks like a couple of 0-values that got written to the syslog - maybe an attack or trojan could cause this.